# Rails routes issue with controller testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, routes

I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong here.  Anyone have any insight?

Here's my routes.rb

```
resources :accounts do
    collection do
        get "search/:term/:offset/:limit.:format", :action => "search", :constraints => { :offset => /\d+/, :limit => /\d+/ }
    end
end
```

Here's my rake routes output...

```
GET    /accounts/search/:term/:offset/:limit.:format    {:offset=>/\d+/, :action=>"search", :controller=>"accounts", :limit=>/\d+/}
```

Here's my test line...

```
get :search, :term => "Test", :offset => 0, :limit => 2
```

Here's my error...

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:term=>"Test", :action=>"search", :controller=>"accounts", :offset=>0, :limit=>2}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issues...

1) It is expecting to match on strings so instead of

```
:offset => 0, :limit => 2
```

it should be

```
:offset => '0', :limit => '2'
```

2) :format was not optional.  I chose to make it an optional param, but if you encounter this you will have to pass format along if you don't make it optional.