# Why does my Rails controller test not route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

Why doesn't my test case work and why does it complain about a route not found? It works in the browser.

#### Code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def deposit
```

#### Routes

```
resources :users do
  post 'deposit', to: :deposit
```

#### Test Case

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "deposit" do
    post :deposit, {id: 1}
```

#### Log

> UsersControllerTest#test_deposit:
> ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:id=>"1", :controller=>"users", :action=>"deposit"}

#### Version

Rails 4.0.0

#### Realated

I saw this, but it did not help when I used '1'. [Rails routes issue with controller testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434764/rails-routes-issue-with-controller-testing)

I saw this, but I already added :id and it still won't work. [Testing Rails 4 Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605118/testing-rails-4-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is your route definition is not so standard.

A better way to add RESTful actions is to use `member`

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post 'deposit'
  end
end
```

Or

```
resources :users do
  post 'deposit', on: :member
end
```

And here is the reason why you can only use `user_id` but not `id`

> You can leave out the :on option, this will create the same member route except that the resource id value will be available in params[:photo_id] instead of params[:id]. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Wow changing that and I had to change all references of `user_deposit_path` to `deposit_user_path`. I almost regret changing it.

Comment: @Chloe, I'm not sure if `as` can work here. If not, it should be very quick to regex search the code base and replace it. Some editor has folder search or "refactor" tool which makes this even faster.

Answer (score 0):

Odd,

```
{user_id: 1}
```

worked. This is one rake route:

> user_deposit POST   /users/:user_id/deposit(.:format)

While this is another:

> edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)